# Shulchan Aruch split into 30 portions

Tags: halacha, shulchan-aruch, publications

Rav Yosef Karo writes in his introduction to the Shulchan Aruch:

, בהיותו שגור בפיו ספר זה הבנוי לתלפיות, תל שהכל פונים בו, לחלקו לחלקים שלושים, ללמוד בו בכל יום חלק, ונמצא שבכל חודש הוא חוזר תלמודו, ויאמר עליו אשרי מי שבא לכאן ותלמודו בידו:

That he split it up into 30 sections and every day a section should be learned and every month the Shulchan Aruch will be completed.

Is there a printed Shulchan Aruch that has these sections written,and how were they divided?

Comment: 1706/30=56.86 Simanim/section.

Comment: thanks,I am assuming that the first edition Had it ,but I have never seen one

Comment: One of the very recent reprints has it. Unsure if it's Oz VeHodor or Shulchan Aruch Hashalem or similar. Will try find it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that meant for people reading it extremely Bekius, who are learning just that during their day, or both? Otherwise, I don’t know how anyone could possibly keep up with that schedule, especially on months with only 29 days.

Comment: @DonielF The Shulchan Arukh is cliff notes for the Beit Yosef. Once you've learned the Beit Yosef, use the ShA for review to keep it fresh in your mind while you go learn other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ketuvim Publishers has the complete Shulchan Aruch with the Rama in one volume. In the introduction the editor explains that the Bais Yosef intended the Shulchan Aruch to be studied and completed every 30 days as I mentioned in my question. The editor also added a complete calender on how the Shulchan Aruch was intended to be learned.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The section called Orach Chaim is actually divided into thirty (unequal) parts. Look in the beginning of each section on the page called לוח הסימנים. There is a title heading for the sections. I'm willing to assume this is what he was reffering to.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. If you look at Luach Davar Be'ito, they have the actual 30 portions, covering all four parts of Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @Shamiach Do you have a link to that online?