# Total number of Simanim In Shulchan Aruch

Tags: number, shulchan-aruch

How many Simanim (Not Seifim) are there in all of Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: This should be a pretty easy thing to just open a book and check, I'd expect. Did you try finding the answer and got stuck somehow? What did you find difficult

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97160/9682

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44362/kitzur-shulchan-aruch-statistics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah/Shulchan%20Arukh) there are

- 697 *simanim* in Orach Chaim
- 402 in Yoreh Deah (as @msh210 and @DoubleAA pointed out, [there is no *siman* 168](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47997/11501) but [there are 2 *simanim* numbered 297](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15866/11501))
- 178 in Even Haezer
- 427 in Choshen Mishpat

**Total: 1704 *simanim***

If you are asking because you want to review (every month [as was the original purpose](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59296/11501), or every year), it would more balanced to split according to [the number of *seifim*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97160/number-of-seifim-in-shulchan-aruch) as some *simanim* are very large.